# Excel to Crm using ssis

Tags: c#, ssis, crm

I have 2 tables in excel in different sheets which have parent and child relationship (foreign key-primarykey) I want to load these tables into Crm using ssis script conponent. I am able to load 2 tables seperately. but I want to load parent table first then loading child tables with parent table as refernce. I saw abt entityreference,lookup but I din't understand exact way to do this. we are using crm 2011and ssis 2014. please help me in this issue.

Comment: It seems that if the references in your second table match the first (parent) table then loading separately should work... Or are you expecting the CRM to create references? Please get some help with your question. It is very difficult to understand.

Comment: No, actually I hav in parent table id will be created using script component that should be populated in child table when am loading data into child table

Comment: What are you doing with the original PK in the parent table (the one the child's FK references)?